# Approve Tag Wikis - Update the description

Tags: discussion, support, tags, privileges

Yesterday I gain the new privilege:

> Approve edits to tag wikis made by regular users
>
> ***You earned this privilege***

On the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) is written this:

> Users with the privilege to vote on tag wikis also have access to the **suggested edit tab** in the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) section.

I still see noting changed in the review page.

> [image]

Is this correct? Where is the suggested edit tab?

I guess the description has to be updated.

Comment: They just appear in the suggested edit queue.

Comment: It's the Suggested Edits task in the list in your picture. It *used* to be a tab. But nonetheless a tag wiki suggestion is still a suggested edit and appears in the same queue. They just get mixed in together.

Comment: @animuson And can't I separe them?

Comment: @Johnツ Not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: @animuson But why "suggested edit" tab when that's not a tab? And why "suggested edit" instead of "Suggested Edits"?

Comment: Because no one has updated that privilege wiki in a long time...

Comment: @animuson Would it be good to ask a new question about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone ahead and expanded the information on the [privilege wiki on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits):

> Users with the privilege to vote on tag wikis will start seeing them appear randomly between other posts in the [Suggested Edits review task](/review/suggested-edits). You can also visit the tag wiki page itself and click on the edit links (similar to a regular post with a suggested edit pending on it) to view the suggestion and vote on it from there.

It will push out to other sites whenever the devs get around to it.

Comment: Yes! The moderator power! Thanks!

Comment: @Johnツ Actually anyone with 1,000 reputation here on Meta can edit the privilege wikis, but only the devs can push the changes out across the network.